# Use drag and drop function to select multiple files and process all

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I need a way to select several files with check-boxes and drag them all to a batch-file icon.  The first step in the script would be to be compressed them into a single zip file before proceeding to the next step.  If possible, it would be useful to also end up with each in a separate zip of its own for storage.

I am not sure how to address the for:to commands to allow gathering all selected files into a single zip file in a script.  The Windows 'sendto compressed zip' function works perfectly if I select all the files the copy and paste them to the Windows ZF filetype.  But I don't know how to access it from within a batch.

Comment: You need to post some code that shows you put some sort of effort into this or you will not get any meaningful responses.  That being said, I will post an answer with a good starting point but it won't be a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Drag and drop multiple files**

By default, if you drag a file onto a batch file it is the same as passing the filepath as a parameter.  This can be accessed using `%%1`.  Dragging multiple files would have a similar effect and be like calling `test.bat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`.  Each "parameter" can be accessed using subsequent variables, `%%1`, `%%2`, `%%3`, etc, up to `%%9`.

[Get more information here.](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)

**Zipping files**

First you will need a utility that supports command line operations, such as [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).  Once you have the appropriate executable in your path, you will need to review the documentation on how to zip files from the command line.  Instead of using the paths and filenames, you will use the variables mentioned above.

Here is some pseudo code:

`zipfiles output.zip %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5`

**Notes**

- You will not be able to drop more than 9 files.
- You may need to confirm that each variable exists.  If you try to include `%%9` in the zip command but you only dropped 8 files, you may get an error.

Comment: When I select multiple files and click sendto: Zip they are all processed into a single zip which would be preferable for the main need.  But I don't see a way to access the ZF filetype in a script.

Comment: What is ZF?  If you use windows "send to" compressed folder, it creates a .ZIP file.  That's what you want to do right?  Zip a bunch of files into a single ZIP file?